# How to configuration Msql 5.7 to provide another access to the database

Tags: server, mysql, configuration

I install mysql 5.7 on ubuntu 16.04 . I grant user complete. But client not connect database on server.
How to configuration Msql 5.7  to client connect and access to the database on mysql-server.

Comment: what is the error of mysql-server when you connect to it? do the mysql client exist on same server of mysql-server?

Answer (score 0):

if the user with the password can login locally but cannot remotely due to `Access denied for user 'user'@'his_ip'`  then
`GRANT ALL ON dbname.* TO 'user'@'his_ip';`

If he can't even connect then check firewall and if mysql listen that interface:
`netstat -plnt | grep 3306`